# Doesn't work JSF annotation @ListenerFor/@ListenersFor

Tags: jsf-2, annotations, listener, systemevent

JSF annotation @ListenerFor doesn't work with GlassFish or Tomcat. No errors or warnings. It's just doesn't call method processEvent().

```
@ListenersFor({@ListenerFor(systemEventClass=PostConstructApplicationEvent.class), 
public class MySystemEventListener implements SystemEventListener {

   @Override
   public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
      if(event instanceof PostConstructApplicationEvent){
         System.out.println("*********************************************");
         System.out.println("processEvent Method is Called: PostConstructApplicationEvent");
         System.out.println("*********************************************");
      }

      if(event instanceof PreDestroyApplicationEvent){
         System.out.println("*********************************************");
         System.out.println("processEvent Method is Called: PreDestroyApplicationEvent");
         System.out.println("*********************************************");
      }
}

   @Override
   public boolean isListenerForSource(Object o) {
      return (o instanceof Application);
   }

}
```

With the idea of​​?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ListenerFor.html) tells you, the `@ListenerFor` is intented to be put on an `UIComponent` or `Renderer` implementation, not on a standalone `SystemEventListener` implementation. For the latter, you'd need to register it as `<system-event-listener>` in `faces-config.xml`.

E.g.

```xml
<application>
    <system-event-listener>
        <system-event-listener-class>com.example.MySystemEventListener</system-event-listener-class>
        <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PostConstructApplicationEvent</system-event-class>
        <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PreDestroyApplicationEvent</system-event-class>
    <system-event-listener>
</application>
```

For the particular functional requirement, you might want to consider to use an eagerly initialized application scoped bean instead. This is somewhat easier and doesn't require some verbose XML:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public void App {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: The linked javadoc does say that the annotation is intended to be put on Application-level listeners too: `If the class to which this annotation is attached implements SystemEventListener and does not implement ComponentSystemEventListener, "target" is the Application instance.`

Comment: Actually the linked javadoc is ambiguous. There is an open [spec issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1020).